# Screen Scraping - By pass Captcha Validation by code [ traffic issue ]

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, httpwebrequest, screen-scraping

I am doing one screen scraping project in asp.net using c#, And I can scrap the screen successfully.
But I have to make one by one multiple requests to the targeted server, but after some time server redirects to **Captcha validation** page, at that time I stuck.

Here is my code :

```
    public static string SearchPage(Uri url, int timeOutSeconds)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            string place = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query).Get("destination").Split(':')[1];
            string resultID = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query).Get("resultID");
            string checkin = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query).Get("checkin").Replace("-", "");
            string checkout = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query).Get("checkout").Replace("-", "");
            string Rooms = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query).Get("Rooms");
            string adults_1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query).Get("adults_1");
            string languageCode = "EN";
            string currencyCode = "INR";
            string ck = "languageCode=" + languageCode + "; a_aid=400; GcRan=1; __RequestVerificationToken=IHZjc7KM_LbUXRypz02LoK4wmeLNcmRpIr-6vmPl5eNepILScAc15vn0TgQJtmABgedDy8xz4bnkqC30_zUGE1A1SaA1; Analytics=LandingID=place:77469:0m&LanguageCode=" + languageCode + "&WebPageID=9; Tests=165F000901000A1100F81000FE110100000102100103100104000105100052; dcid=dal05; currencyCode=" + currencyCode + "; countryCode=" + languageCode + "; search=place:" + place + "#" + checkin + "#" + checkout + "#" + adults_1 + "; SearchHistory=" + place + "%" + checkin + "%" + checkout + "%" + adults_1 + "%" + currencyCode + "%%11#" + place + "%" + checkin + "%" + checkout + "%" + adults_1 + "%" + currencyCode + "%%" + resultID + "#; visit=date=2015-11-23T18:26:05.4922127+11:00&id=45111733-acef-47d1-aed3-63cef1a60591; visitor=id=efff4190-a4a0-41b5-b807-5d18e4ee6177&tracked=true";


            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Timeout = timeOutSeconds * 1000;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = timeOutSeconds * 1000;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36 OPR/33.0.1990.115";
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            request.Headers.Add("Cookie", ck);
            request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
            request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

            string line = reader.ReadToEnd();

            sb.Append(line);
            sb.Replace("<br/>", Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Replace("\t", " ");

            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            request.Abort();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //throw ex;
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This code works successfully but after some requests it stuck because may be server allows some limited requests.

Comment: You understand captcha is there to prevent what you are doing right? So is the question how to solve a captcha?

Comment: Yes Ron.. My question is how to solve a captcha?